# access allow orgin between two pages of mine

Tags: javascript, iframe, cordova, cross-domain

hi i am developing a **phonegap** app and i need to make a page which holds **google maps** to access the phonegap page the problem is that i can't get pass the **same-orgin-policy** 
between the two pages . is there any way to allow such behavior knowing that the two pages are under my grip !

the scenario : 
the page from server with domain "localhost" would trigger a custom event in the parent page in the phonegap application which holds an iframe to the server page knowing that phonegap application domain will always be different than the server domain

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a custom event, try `window.postMessage`. You provide the whitelisted domains as a second argument to the function. 
Incidentally, to the phonegap application, once it is deployed, the google maps page won't be on localhost, it will be hosted somewhere (how else would the user access it?), so you'll need to update the postMessage accordingly.